# Filtering using URL with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to do basic filtering using my URL. I have tried several solutions without success.

Please propose a straight forward solution. Surely there is a generic solution

Here is my code:

## Models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    level = models.IntegerField("Level", null=True, blank=True)
```

## Views.py

```
class TagFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(owner=request.user)
```

## Urls.py

```
router.register(r'tag', TagViewSet)
```

I want to be able to filter like this:

```
xyz.com/tag?level=40/
```

To display all items with a level of 40 only.

Using django-filter (not to be mistaken for DjangoFilter**S**), I created a new filters.py file.

However, the results never get filtered. When I hit the API url, it just gives me all results.

## Filter.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from Tril.models import Tag
from .serializers import TagSerializer

class TagFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = filters.NumberFilter(level="level", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_price = filters.NumberFilter(level="level", lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ['level', 'name']


class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = TagFilter
```

Comment: Why `level="level"` in `FilterSet` and what is `taglevel` field when the field name in the `Tag` model is `level` instead?

Comment: Fixed that up- was a paste error

Comment: You can also consider using https://github.com/manjitkumar/drf-url-filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used django-filter, and the URL filter instead. Minimal code was required. I recommend this over django-filters.

I would also like to be able to combine levels (eg write api/level/1&2&3) but if no one answers I understand it is outside the scope of my original question.

## filters.py

```
from rest_framework import filters, generics
from .serializers import TagSerializer
from Tril.models import Tag

class TagLevel(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        taglevel = self.kwargs['level']
        return Tag.objects.filter(level=level)
```

## urls.py

`url('^level/(?P<level>.+)/$', Level.as_view()`